# 4-momentum conservation vertex-by-vertex in diagrams -- reference with explicit statement

Tags: momentum, conservation-laws, resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams

A friend of mine does not believe that four-momentum is conserved independently in each vertex of a Feynman-diagram; and, as a consequence, that propagators/virtual particles do not obey a dispersion relation.

They won't trust my claims, and pointing out that this definition is the one producing correct cross-sections for any specific example does not appear to suffice.
I know, however, that they would trust a "reputable" book (not Wikipedia). Could you help me find a quote which is as explicit as possible, from a source as authoritative as possible?

A "proof" would surely be welcome but is not necessary: a trusted source making the claim unambiguously will be sufficient here.

---

My failed attempt: in "Relativistic Quantum Mechanics" of Bjorken and Drell, section 7.4 ("Electron Scattering frorn a Dirac Proton"), I find:

> "The wavy line represents [....]. We refer to this line as representing a "virtual photon" exchanging four-momentum $q = p_f - p_i = P_i - P_f$.

Bjorken and Drell are probably trying to suggest the idea that virtual particles need not to be more than a mathematical tool. However, that sentence can be read as if the situation is a mere accident and not something general. I could not find in the text an explicit "at each vertex both the energy and momentum are conserved"; neither does appendix B explicitly say "at each vertex, add a Dirac $\delta$ which will cancel a 4-momentum integral" (it does say "For each internal momentum $l$ not fixed by momentum conservation constraints at vertices, add a factor [...]", but I can see how this sentence is really clear only after the point is understood).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want authoritative statement to quote it's point $4$ in section 7.3 of Schwartz QFT.  And if want to them the reason as well it's following:

We are essentially calculating fourier transform of $e^{ix(...)}$ w.r.t. to $x$ and where dots are for the sum of momentum at the vertex and in position space feynman diagram the value of $x$ at the vertex covers all of the spacetime.